# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, pie-chart

FULL ERROR :

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: object 'counts' not found.
```

I am trying to create a pie chart with the VARIABLE `RatingStatus` filtered to "Unrated".

Can anyone provide guidance on the cause of the error??

ALso I would love to provide 'reproducable' content to you guys but lost on how to use the dput() function!! If someone could please explain that too it would be very much appreciated. I looked at the thread but still dont get the mechanics of going through it as my df is huge!

```
df <- 
    ibg %>% 
    arrange(desc(RatingStatus == "UNRATED")) %>% 
    mutate(prop = round(counts*100/sum(counts),1),
          lab.ybos = cumsum(prop) -.5*prop)


dput(head(stack,1, 10))
structure(list(RatingStatus = "RATED"), .Names = "RatingStatus", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: there's nothing called "counts" in ibg/your workspace?

Comment: Add the output of `str(ibg)` or `colnames(ibg)` to your question, very likely the column is named differently than `counts`.

Comment: @griffinevo no there isnt.. so that needs to be defined?.I guess I thought it was a function that would count the varaible!

Comment: there is a function `count`. Maybe use that first

Comment: Nope. Use `n()` to get counts of observations, though you probably want to pair that with a `group_by`. Posting your data will allow folks to help you, or point us to a common dataset that ships with R and could serve as an example

Comment: Hi @camille, placed dput() above - does that help?

Comment: The data you posted is just one observation of one variable. `head(stack, 1)` means only the first row of the dataframe. Take a look at the docs for `dput`